# ACRA does not send report crash using HttpSender

Tags: android, acra

I installed the Acre extension as written in the acre documentation.
And added the `@AcraHttpSender` anatomy indicated the site and the sending method in it.
But when I throw an exception or use the following command `ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(new Exception("123"));`, nothing happens to the server.
Although I have a permission to access the network in the manifest and the Internet is always on.

Why is not sending?

And is there a way to manually send accumulated reports using the service after a certain period of time?

Comment: Can you share your code. FYI ACRA needs a gmail emailID and Password for configuration to trigger the email

Comment: Check your logcat for messages with the `ACRA` tag. What @Arshad said is false, email is only required for EmailSender, password is never required.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong, I checked the data in the `$_POST` array, which produced a negative result and the logs were not written, you should use the input stream reading directly like this `file_get_contents('php://input');`

The question can be considered closed, thank you all, the ACRA logs helped to see that the data is not written to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. If it helps anyone else out, here is my **MyApplication.java**:

```
@AcraCore(
        buildConfigClass = BuildConfig.class,
        reportFormat = StringFormat.JSON
)
@AcraHttpSender(
        uri = "https://example.org/my_acra_script.php",
        httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST
)
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);

        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
    }

}
```

...just change the `uri` value.

And here is **my_acra_script.php**:

```
<?php

$NEW_LINE = "\r\n";

$from = "server@example.org";
$to = "you@example.org";
$subject = "Android Crash Report";

$headers  = "From: $from" . $NEW_LINE;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $NEW_LINE;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . $NEW_LINE;

$message  = "<html>";
$message .= "    <head>";
$message .= "        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />";
$message .= "        <title>$subject</title>";
$message .= "    </head>";
$message .= "    <body>";
$message .= "        <p>";

$post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');

if (empty($post_data)) {
    $message .= "No data received.";
}
else {
    $error_data = json_decode($post_data, true);

    foreach ($error_data as $key => $value) {
        $message .= "<br /><b>" . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($key)) . ":</b><br />" . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($value)) . "<br />" . $NEW_LINE;
    }
}
$message .= "        </p>";
$message .= "    </body>";
$message .= "</html>";

$result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($result === TRUE) {
    echo "OK";
}
else {
    error_log("ACRA email not sent.");
}

?>
```

...just change the `$from` and `$to` values.